# Can Caddy V1 apply GZIP compression to a proxied response?

Tags: gzip, reverse-proxy, caddy, caddyfile

I'm running Caddy v1 as a reverse proxy and I would like to apply GZIP compression on e.g. JSON responses.

I noticed that the `gzip` Caddy v1 directive only applies on files Caddy serves its self but not on responses where Caddy runs a reverse proxy with the `proxy` directive.

```
0.0.0.0:8080 {
    gzip {
      ext *
      level 9
    }
    log stdout
    errors stdout

    proxy /api/v2 127.0.0.1:50010 {
          transparent
          without /api/v2
    }
}
```

Is there a way to compress the proxied response body or is this not possible with Caddy?

Comment: Due to the fact that there is Caddy v2 and Caddy v1 is not anymore supported this question can be considered as obsolete. GZIP in V2 works as expected